# inside array of arrays if there is missing index then add empty index for missing index

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

//this is the array is have and the below is what i want

```
$data = array(
    array(
            'title' => 'My title',
            'date' => 'My date'
    ),
    array(
            'title' => 'Another title',
            'name' => 'Another Name'
    ),
    array(
            'name' => 'Another Name',
            'date' => 'Another date'
    ),
    array(
            'date' => 'Another date',
            'name' => 'Another Name'
    )
);
```

//result which i want

```
$data = array(
    array(
            'title' => 'My title',
            'name' => '',
            'date' => 'My date'
    ),
    array(
            'title' => 'Another title',
            'name' => 'Another Name',
            'date' => ''
    ),
    array(
            'title' => '',
            'name' => 'Another Name',
            'date' => 'Another date'
    ),
    array(
            'title' => '',
            'name' => 'Another Name',
            'date' => 'Another date'
    )
);
```

Comment: Can you please share your actual array which is you want to convert like your result array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using array_map();

```
$data=array_map(function($element){
return [
    'title'=>isset($element['title'])?$element['title']:'',
    'name'=>isset($element['name'])?$element['name']:'',
    'date'=>isset($element['date'])?$element['date']:''
    ];
```

},$data);
print_r($data);

[solution](https://3v4l.org/usOQS)